# Couldn't get the binded values into the list

Tags: javascript, html, list

```
    <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list"> <span class="anchor">Select State</span>
       <ul class="items" data-bind="foreach:carTypes" onchange="GetSelectedValut1()">
          <li>
             <label>
                <input id="items1" type="checkBox" /><span id="vv1" data-bind="text:text,value:text"></span>
             </label>

          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Want all the values of the cartypes when i check the box. geting only one (top most one) value here.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function GetSelectedValut1() {
    if (document.getElementById('items1').checked) {
        var list_value = document.getElementById("vv1").value;
        document.getElementById("vall1").innerHTML = list_value;
    } else document.getElementById("vall1").innerHTML = "";

}
```

want all the values of the cartypes when i check the box. geting only one(top most one) value here. my event to get the values is it sufficient here.

Comment: show your javascript code too!

Comment: Check this line `document.getElementById("vall1").innerHTML = list_value;` And is there anything with ID "vall1"?

Comment: yes...for UI .to display at output <p id="vall1"></p>

Comment: Can you change this line value to innerHTML at `var list_value = document.getElementById("vv1").value;`

Comment: you mean instead of value to innerHTML .right???.wait

Comment: same result is displaying. No change Vikas. thanks.

Comment: same result means? are you getting any result or error? I just read that you mentioned that you are getting first result, is that correct? if so then one question is all the inputs have same id "items1"?